# How to display data in table using lodash in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, lodash, angular8

I'm trying to display data in a table using lodash using angular 9 but when I'm pass data to a variable then it shows nothing.

**Heare is my Code**

Component.ts

```
list =[]
constructor(private apiservice: ApiServiceService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.apiservice.filterData().then(resData => {
   _.forEach(resData, boxes => {
     _.forEach(boxes, data => {
       _.forEach(data, val => {
          if(val.name === 'GIP_asOfDate'){
           _.forEach(val, asOfDate =>{
            _.forEach(asOfDate, asd =>{
               this.list = asd;
              // console.log(this.list)
                //  console.log(asd.Name)
                //  console.log(asd.Count)
            })
           })
         }
       });
     });
   });
  });
 }
```

component.html

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>As of Date</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of list">
         <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
         <td>{{item.Count}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: did you check if you are you getting data in the list?

Comment: Console log is working or not